# how to declare a variable in session scope using spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

I want a variable which is updating dynamically and should be in session scope. i am  using spring MVC. when i declared the variable in controller class as class variable the variable is getting updated across all users looks like in application scope. I want that should be updated individually.

suppose if am using a counter to increment initially the value is 0. user A logged in and the variable value is updated to 1. if user B logged in and the variable value is updated to 2 which should be updated to 1 only(as per my requirement) i want the variable value in session scope.

Comment: You could decorate your `@Controller` with `@Scope("session")` as shown here: http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i want to declare a variable which should be specific to that user who logged in.

Comment: Have you tried something like request.getPortletSession().setAttribute("counter", 1); If this is wide of the mark please post some code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Session Scoped bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-global-session) containing the `List` or Set the `List` as a `HttpSession` attribute.

Comment: my flow of execution in liferay portlet is when i click on add button in popup window, a method will be called in which am adding the bean object to a list(which is a class variable).if i click on add button multiple times the method will be called multiple times. so where i have to define the session variable. the session variable value should be updated each time i clicked on add. please tell me if you need more inputs.

Comment: I updated the question with clear explaination once see that.